# Finding the real roots of an $n$-th degree polynomial with 2 terms

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is it possible to find the real roots of the polynomial of this form $ax^n+bx^{n-1}+c = 0$?

If $c=0$, this would be trivial, but I am not sure how to handle this case...

**Edit:** It is known that all coefficients are real and $a < 0$, $b>0$, $b = |a| + 1$.

Comment: In general, the answer is no because of the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), which states that there is no general formula for solving a polynomial of degree five or higher. There are of course some special cases as you have mentioned.

Comment: If $n$ is even, then real roots cant exists. Example $-7 x^8 + 8 x^7 - 11=0$.

Comment: Possible cant exists

Comment: @TobyMak, thank you for this. Would you like to post this as an answer, so I can close this question?